# Scrapy Shell and Scrapy Splash

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapy-shell, splash-js-render

We've been using [`scrapy-splash` middleware](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash) to pass the scraped HTML source through the `Splash` javascript engine running inside a docker container.

If we want to use Splash in the spider, we configure several [required project settings](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash#configuration) and yield a `Request` specifying specific [`meta` arguments](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash#usage):

```
yield Request(url, self.parse_result, meta={
    'splash': {
        'args': {
            # set rendering arguments here
            'html': 1,
            'png': 1,

            # 'url' is prefilled from request url
        },

        # optional parameters
        'endpoint': 'render.json',  # optional; default is render.json
        'splash_url': '<url>',      # overrides SPLASH_URL
        'slot_policy': scrapyjs.SlotPolicy.PER_DOMAIN,
    }
})
```

This works as documented. But, how can we use `scrapy-splash` inside the [Scrapy Shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)?

Comment: It's true there's no `DEFAULT_REQUEST_META` like there is a [DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?#std:setting-DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS) which would be a nice addition. There are open discussions on enabling Splash by default via a middleware (see https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash/issues/11). Another option is to subclass scrapy-splash mdw and force settings there. Ideas welcome on https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash/issues

Answer (score 43, accepted):

just wrap the URL you want to shell to in [splash HTTP API](http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api.html#render-html).

So you would want something like:

```
scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://example.com/page-with-javascript.html&timeout=10&wait=0.5'
```

where:

- `localhost:port` is where your splash service is running
- `url` is URL you want to crawl and don't forget to **urlquote** it!
- `render.html` is one of the possible HTTP API endpoints, returns redered HTML page in this case
- `timeout` time in seconds for timeout
- `wait` time in seconds to wait for JavaScript to execute before reading/saving the HTML.

Comment: you can probably make a bash alias to make this more convenient.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller you just uppercased some words and ruined the formatting.

Comment: Something is funky with the markdown formatting, I've never seen trailing white space introduce new lines in the output.  Using list formatting will prevent preserve the new lines.  I also use `example.com` instead of a non-example `.com` which is the main reason for the edit.

Answer (score 19):

You can run `scrapy shell` without arguments inside a configured Scrapy project, then create `req = scrapy_splash.SplashRequest(url, ...)` and call `fetch(req)`.

Answer (score 0):

For the windows users, who use Docker Toolbox:

1. Change the single inverted comma with double inverted comma for preventing the `invalid hostname:http` error.
2. change the localhost to the docker IP address which is below the whale logo. for me it was `192.168.99.100`.

Finally I got this:

`scrapy shell "http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html?url="https://example.com/category/banking-insurance-financial-services/""`