# Scrapy crawl site with dynamic routing

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

How can I scrape all tools from site with dynamic routing

http://growthtools.io/social-media-automation-tools

When I was trying to

```
scrapy shell 'http://growthtools.io/social-media-automation-tools'
```

I recieved following result

```
2017-01-07 22:43:06 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
2017-01-07 22:43:06 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger

In [1]: view(response)
```

[image]

and `response` object did't contain `tools` elements.

```
In [3]: In [2]: response.css('.toolsList')
Out[3]: []
In [5]: 'toolsList' in response.body
Out[5]: False
```

Who can describe how can I parse http://growthtools.io/social-media-automation-tools and why `reponse` object did't contain all page content?

Comment: The site uses JavaScript to display the page. You should use a headless browser like Splash or PhantomJS to render it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The page load involves JavaScript executed by the browser which Scrapy is not*. You can though solve it with [`scrapy-splash`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) which provides a *middleware* to use in your Scrapy project. The middleware uses the [`Splash` JS rendering service](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which you can run through the docker.

As far as testing it in the Scrapy Shell, you can follow [this example to run it from the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352423/scrapy-shell-and-scrapy-splash).

Works for me:

```
$ scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://growthtools.io/social-media-automation-tools' 
In [1]: response.css('.toolsList')
Out[1]: 
[<Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' toolsList ')]" data=u'<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 toolsLis'>,
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' toolsList ')]" data=u'<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 toolsLis'>,
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' toolsList ')]" data=u'<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 toolsLis'>,
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' toolsList ')]" data=u'<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 toolsLis'>,
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' toolsList ')]" data=u'<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 toolsLis'>,
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' toolsList ')]" data=u'<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 toolsLis'>,
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' toolsList ')]" data=u'<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 toolsLis'>,
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' toolsList ')]" data=u'<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 toolsLis'>,
 <Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' toolsList ')]" data=u'<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 toolsLis'>]
```