# Scrapy/Splash Click on a button then get content from new page in new window

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I'm facing a problem that when I click on a button, then Javascript handle the action then it redirect to a new page with new window (It's similar to when you click on `<a>` with target `_Blank`). In the scrapy/splash I don't know how to get content from the new page (I means I don't know how to control that new page).

Anyone can help!

```
script = """
    function main(splash)
        assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
        splash:wait(0.5)
        local element = splash:select('div.result-content-columns div.result-title')
        local bounds = element:bounds()
        element:mouse_click{x=bounds.width/2, y=bounds.height/2}
        return splash:html()
    end
"""

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': self.script})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue:

The problem that you can't scrape html which is out of your selection scope. When a new link is clicked, if there is an iframe involved, it rarely brings it into scope for scraping.

## Solution:

Choose a method of selecting the new iframe, and then proceed to parse the new html.

## The Scrapy-Splash method

(This is an adaptation of Mikhail Korobov's solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657613/scrapy-splash-scraping-element-inside-inner-html))

If you are able to get the src link of the new page that pops up, it may be the most reliable, however, you can also try selecting iframe this way:

```
# ...
    yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result, endpoint='render.json', 
                        args={'html': 1, 'iframes': 1})

def parse_result(self, response):
    iframe_html = response.data['childFrames'][0]['html']
    sel = parsel.Selector(iframe_html)
    item = {
        'my_field': sel.xpath(...),
        # ...  
    }
```

## The Selenium method

(requires pip install selenium,bs4, and possibly a chrome driver download from here for your os: [Selenium Chromedrivers](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)) Supports Javascript parsing! Woohoo!

With the following code, this will switch scopes to the new frame:

```
# Goes at the top
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# Your path depends on where you downloaded/located your chromedriver.exe
CHROME_PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver.exe'
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") # Speeds things up if you don't need gui
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)

chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)

url = "example_js_site.com" # Your site goes here
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3) # An unsophisticated way to wait for the new page to load.
browser.switch_to.frame(0)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip(), 'lxml')

# This will return any content found in tags called '<table>'
table = soup.find_all('table')
```

My favorite of the two options is Selenium, but try the first solution if you are more comfortable with it!

Comment: Added the code, please take a look. I wondering that What library of `browser` come from? does scrapy-splash support it?

Comment: @SangHuynh Selenium

Comment: It's great, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SangHuynh If this worked for you, could you please accept it as the answer?