# I can't render this web page using splash

Tags: iframe, scrapy, scrapy-splash

For some reason, I cannot render this webpage https://pa.parxcasino.com/kambiSportsbook.shtml#filter/ufc_mma using splash I tried all of the tips in the Splash FAQ here: https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly .

I also figured it may be an issue with the content being in an iframe and tried using this answer [Scrapy + Splash: scraping element inside inner html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657613/scrapy-splash-scraping-element-inside-inner-html) as a reference but I still can't seem to find the HTML I need in it either.

I am trying to get this section:
[image]

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know you specifically ask for rendering the page using Splash, but if you are just after the data, you can use the API to get it - https://eu-offering.kambicdn.org/offering/v2018/parxuspa/listView/ufc_mma.json?lang=en_US&market=US&client_id=2&channel_id=1&ncid=1592554293710&useCombined=true

Comment: Where can I learn more on using this API?

Comment: Well, that's just what you can see in browser's developer tools. Open up the browser, open the developer tools and switch to XHR tab. Then visit the page and see what APIs it queries.

Comment: How can I grab this URL and parse it though using scrapy?

Comment: I actually understand how to parse it but is the only way to grab it by just using that exact URL?  Is there a more flexible way to grab the JSON url using the base url?

Comment: For anyone interested, this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7nQ41NVPN0 had an amazing explanation of the process that really helped me out.