# Can't render sephora.com.au/brands using Splash

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to render this page https://www.sephora.com.au/brands using Splash.

But it returns: 
'Unfortunately, your web browser does not have JavaScript enabled at this moment, which will cause errors if you proceed on our website.'

Is there any solution to this problem?
Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62459023/i-cant-render-this-web-page-using-splash

Comment: use scrapy-selenium

Comment: @Alexander scrapy-selenium is working, but I was looking for something faster