# running splash on scrapy shell

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapy-shell

Im trying to scrape a site that requires logging in.  so i login.

The pages directly after the login seem to have alot of javascript.

How can i test out the responses of splash on scrapy shell?

Once i login, how can i run splash on the next url via splash command line and have it process the javascript and give me a response i can parse?

I dont understand what i actually need to do to run the splash service and how it functions with scrapy...  Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352423 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy Shell and Scrapy Splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352423/scrapy-shell-and-scrapy-splash)

Comment: Regarding your question part that is not duplicate on how to run splash check out official installation documentation: https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html In short Splash is a http service that you install, run and then connect from your apps to render some web pages